# Is it necessary to add a `FloatLayout` inside a `Widget`?

Tags: python, widget, kivy

If I have a class that I define in the Python source file as a child of `Widget`, is it necessary for me add a `FloatLayout` a child, or can I just position the elements inside the `Widget` directly, without using a `FloatLayout` at all?

```
# Python source
class FooBar(Widget):
    pass

# Kivy source
<FooBar>:
    FloatLayout:  # Is this necessary? 
        SomeChildWidget:
            ...
        AnotherChildWidget:
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with embed widgets inside widgets. You are in complete control of the position and sizing.

The [`add_widget`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=widget#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget) method (and `children property`) is part of the [`Widget`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=widget#kivy.uix.widget) class, and [`Layout`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html?highlight=layout#kivy.uix.layout) just inherits from `Widget`. As an example, the [Kivy pong tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html) doesn't have any layouts.

**Note:** If you are start wondering about the difference of using `Widget` and [`FloatLayout`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html#kivy.uix.floatlayout.FloatLayout). Basically, the latter honours Widget.pos_hint and Widget.size_hint attributes. It allows you to use proportional values to the size of the `Widget` for positioning.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look over the [Kv language documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) suggests that no, you don't need a layout inside the widget. Consider the example they give [under the template section](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#templates):

```
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello world, watch this text wrap inside the button"
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: '25sp'
        markup: True
    Button:
        text: "Even absolute is relative to itself"
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: '25sp'
        markup: True
    Button:
        text: "Repeating the same thing over and over in a comp = fail"
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: '25sp'
        markup: True
```

Here 3 button widgets have been placed directly under the `<MyWidget>` declaration.

Comment: I've noticed that the behavior and look of the widget is what I want it to be, but I was wondering if this is just a consequence of the implementation or if it's really the desired behavior of the library.